# Background task in Typescript

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript

I'm new in Angular 2 and typescript and used to do this in Java or Golang :

I have a service with a stack and a routine that make a background (asynchronous) task only one time, on each element of this stack...

I don't want to know who is pushing something in my stack and how it does, but I need to process each element in an inconspicuous asynchronous task.

*Edit : the task is a request and I want to group all the stack's elements in an array*

If I use Javascript interval to check my stack, I finally obtains some lags regardless of frequency.

I know there is no thread notion in Typescript, but maybe a kind of best practice for background tasks ?